# Keyboard macro to skip AD

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, video

With the advent of Cord Cutters people switched from TV to the Internet. Now ADs are appearing on the internet. For example this movie AD appears halfway through a video:

[image: Skip AD]

On the left you see a play button. When you click it the lower right section changes from "Skip this in 5 s." to "4 s" then "3 s" until "Skip AD" appears.

I'd like to create a macro that:

- Mutes volume
- Clicks the play icon
- Watches until "Skip AD" appears when countdown ends (note it can be 25 seconds)
- Restores volume
- Clicks the "Skip AD" icon

I appreciates google's entrepreneurship in turning the internet into old school TV advertising but in turn they will appreciate our efforts to not watch ads that are annoying.

Comment: Do you still see ads with when playing the url via mpv or vlc? As for the macro, it would have to be very sentient!

Comment: @JusticeforMonica I haven't tried watching via `vlc` only direct through browser. How is Monica doing these days?

Comment: Praying for her! I use mpv and don't see ads but then the content I watch isn't "popular". But still, give it a try. I even have a small script launched by a keyboard shortcut that makes a right-click (via xdotool) on a YouTube link in Firefox (not any other browser) straight to mpv://`#!/bin/sh`//`xdotool click 3 && sleep 0.3 && xdotool key a && sleep 0.3 && mpv "$(xclip -o)"`.